# deleteObject hangs my app

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
TTNetworkDataSource* netSource = [TTNetworkDataSource sharedSource];
    [netSource setContext:self];

    TTDataSourceResponse* districtsResponse = [netSource requestDataWithQuery:@{@(OBJECT_TYPE): [HotlineDistrict clsName]}];


    if (districtsResponse != nil) {
        NSArray* objects = [self executeFetchRequestUnsafe:[NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:[HotlineDistrict clsName]] error:&localError];

        NSInteger i = 0;

        if (localError != nil) {
            result = NO; return;
        } else {
            NSLog(@"%lu = fetchedObjects, %lu = districtsResponse", (unsigned long)objects.count, (unsigned long)districtsResponse.objects.count);
            for (NSManagedObject* obj in objects) {
                NSLog(@"Deleted Objects in fetched objects %ld", (unsigned long)i++);
                [self deleteObject:obj];
            }

            for (NSManagedObject* obj in districtsResponse.objects) {
                NSLog(@"Inserted Object in districtsResponse %ld", (unsigned long)i++);
                [self insertObject:obj];
            }
        }
    } else {
        localError = [NSError errorInfo:@{NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: @"Error when getting districts."}];
        result = NO;
    }

    TTDataSourceResponse* requestTypeResponse = [netSource requestDataWithQuery:@{@(OBJECT_TYPE): [HotlineRequestType clsName]}];


    if (requestTypeResponse != nil) {
        NSArray* objects = [self executeFetchRequestUnsafe:[NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:[HotlineRequestType clsName]] error:&localError];

        NSInteger j = 0;

        if (localError != nil) {
            result = NO; return;
        } else {
            NSLog(@"%lu = fetchedObjects, %lu = requestTypeResponse", (unsigned long)objects.count, (unsigned long)requestTypeResponse.objects.count);
            for (NSManagedObject* obj in objects) {
                NSLog(@"Deleted Objects in fetched objects %ld", (unsigned long)j++);
                [self deleteObject:obj];
            }

            for (NSManagedObject* obj in requestTypeResponse.objects) {
                NSLog(@"Deleted Objects in requestTypeResponse %ld", (unsigned long)j++);
                [self insertObject:obj];
            }
        }
    } else {
        localError = [NSError errorInfo:@{NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: @"Error when getting request types."}];
        result = NO;
    }
```

Here's my code, after [self deleteObject:obj] my app hangs

Manual debug by:

```
NSLog(@"%lu = fetchedObjects, %lu = districtsResponse", (unsigned long)objects.count, (unsigned long)districtsResponse.objects.count);
```

Give this result:

> 802 = fetchedObjects, 47 = districtsResponse

NSLogs in loops give enumeration of objects, in total we have summ of fetchedObjects and districtsResponse, even if place NSLog in the end of loop body. So its says that loop finished well. But the app is hangs. Those loops 2, it don't touch second loop, and if we delete those loops with deleteObject - it works.

Comment: Is this code running in a Async_Block or other own Thread? CoreData is not working in background threads.

Comment: You have 2 `deleteObject` calls in separate for loops - which one is causing it to hang?

Comment: Claus, i'm not sure, but i think it's on sync thread, all this construction in the [self performUpdateBlockAndWait: ^{...my code...}]; which refers to
- (void)performUpdateBlockAndWait:(void (^)())updateBlock {
    dispatch_sync(update_queue, updateBlock);
}

noobsmcgoobs, both, if delete first loop, it hangs on the second

Guys, sorry for my english, and i'm newbie in objc

Comment: Are you removing the object from its list/array in deleteObject()? Because you must not change an array while you iterate on it.

Comment: i think no, there is only one operation: deleteObject
Apple documentation says: Specifies an object that should be removed from its persistent store when changes are committed.

Comment: Now I am confused. deleteObject() is the CoreData function itself? In this case your class must be of type ManagedObjectContext? I dont think this will work. I would not beleive, that the context keeps the same all the time.

Comment: Yes, this is subclass of NSManagedObjectContext

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, our api sended nil values to the required attribute in entity, but anyway, thanks a lot guys

Answer (score 0):

You must not subclass NSManagedObjectContext as Apple says:

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/index.html

Subclassing Notes
You are strongly discouraged from subclassing NSManagedObjectContext. The change tracking and undo management mechanisms are highly optimized and hence intricate and delicate. Interposing your own additional logic that might impact processPendingChanges can have unforeseen consequences. In situations such as store migration, Core Data will create instances of NSManagedObjectContext for its own use. Under these circumstances, you cannot rely on any features of your custom subclass. Any NSManagedObject subclass must always be fully compatible with NSManagedObjectContext (that is, it cannot rely on features of a subclass of NSManagedObjectContext).

Comment: Subclassing `NSManagedObjectContext` is not a sin if you are creating class factory methods.  It's actually quite useful.  What's more likely to be the issue is using the GCD `dispatch_sync` in combination with MOCs that have their own queues.  Should use `performBlockAndWait`...